# How to add _destroy flag to RestKit PUT request when using Rails nested_attributes

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, restkit, nested-attributes

I have a Rails project that uses nested attributes and thus during a PUT request it needs to know which child objects to delete. For example this is the request I need to send:

`{
  "playlist": {
    "name": "Playlist Name",
    "playlist_artists_attributes": [
      {
        "id": 1087,
        "artist_id": 1208,
      },
      {
        "id": 1086,
        "artist_id": 1207,
        "_destroy": true
      }
    ],
  }
}`

I am currently using RestKit's default object serialization which sends a request like so:

`{
  "playlist": {
    "name": "Playlist Name",
    "playlist_artists_attributes": [
      {
        "id": 1087,
        "artist_id": 1208,
      }
    ],
  }
}`

Which as you see only sends the artists I want to keep when editing a playlist. Is there an easy way to change RestKit's object serialization to support adding a _destroy flag to deleted artists (I imagine not since I need to keep delete artist info around) or would it be easier to change how the Rails app handles PUT requests for this object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the ability to change the model and the `playlist_artists_attributes` of the object you're going to `PUT`, I'd add a transient attribute to the object in the `playlist_artists_attributes` list, called `destroyDuringUpload`. In the serialisation mapping, map `@"destroyDuringUpload" : @"_destroy"`, then add the object and flag the item to be destroyed and you're done.